# Automating ipython output to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a little program that basically does all kinds of statistical calculation and prints out results and charts.

At present, a convenient way to get a nice pdf output of my program is to run my code in Jupyter IPython Notebook using magic command %matplotlib inline and save as pdf by doing "PDF via LaTex(.pdf) "

But, the problem is I have to do it manually every time I run the program. In addition, I cannot deliver the program as binary executable to other people, which is my final goal.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?  Just to be clear, all I want is output of my program in pdf format so that when the executable is run, the output is pdf. **I don't want the end user to create ipython notebook.** The end user will not have access to the source code.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

As of now there's not a programming language API to convert notebooks to PDF. However, a command line utility exists called [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert). It has the same functionality as the web interface's format converters. To convert to PDF, you can do `jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to pdf`.

Luckily, Python has a handy [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) which allows you to spawn new processes, check their inputs and outputs, and get their return codes. So you could do something like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to pdf")
```

Kind of a hacky way, but it will work. If you're using Windows, you may need to add the additional kwarg `shell=True` to `subprocess.call()`

Comment: nbconvert also has a Python API that you can use, though it's a bit more complicated for simple cases than the command line. http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html

Comment: This solution is not going to work since this requires the user to create ipython notebook.

Comment: `subprocess.call` doesn't accept string. You should pass `subprocess.call(shlex.split("jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to pdf"))`

Answer (score 3):

If you have an IPython notebook, you can make a small python or bash script that first executes and then produces the PDF. For me, this bash script works:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=500 --to notebook --execute my_file.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf my_file.nbconvert.ipynb
rm my_file.nbconvert.ipynb
```

If you want to customise the output using a template, I have found that converting the file first to markdown and then using pandoc to create a PDF avoids some issues:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=500 --to notebook --execute my_file.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert  --to markdown my_file.nbconvert.ipynb  --template="mytemplate.tpl"
pandoc --toc --template=mytemplate.tex markdown my_file.nbconvert.ipynb --latex-engine=pdflatex -o final file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows if you want to convert **recursively** you can use git-bash window and do something like this:

```
$ find /d/we_are_on_disk_d/path_to_ipynb_files/ -name '*.ipynb' | xargs jupyter nbconvert --to [script|pdf]
```