# How to export/save to pdf with pie/doughnut chart in matplotlib or any related lib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I need to attach a PDF in an email with a custom HTML tables and doughnut chart to represent some savings.

I was able to find only paid APIs. I would like to achieve this functionality with an existing library. I have tried `matplotlib`, `reportlab`, e.t.c.

I need to render charts directly in an email body or with PDF format as an attachment.

Comment: Do you just want to have the chart in your email with a fixed text, or do you also need to add tables? If it's just the chart, maybe you could export the chart as an image and program the rest yourself?

Comment: Need to add chart as part of mail content along with some table information about chart desc.

Comment: I haven't done something like that, but maybe you could see, if this post helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988699/automating-ipython-output-to-pdf. You could maybe prepare a nice `jupyter` notebook, see if you can setup an automatic update process and store the result as a pdf if you get no better sugestions.